# Parser in Haskell for Triples

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming

I am currently doing an assignment about Parsing in Haskell, but I am struggling with some of the basics.

**Assignment** :
I am supposed to create a function which parses a string into a list of Triples.
So that:
A, B, C
  ,E ,D

would result in

```
Triples [("A","B","C"), ("A","E","D")]
```

The input string is going to include ;\n as an indication for the beginng of a new Triple. The string is going to end with a dot.
The elements of the Triples can be letters or digits or combination, 
e.g. abc, a, 1, abc121.

Therefore,

```
"a,b,c;\n d,e;\n f,g;\n h,i."
```

would result in:

```
Triples [("a","b","c"),("a","d","e"),("a","f","g"),("a","h","i")]
```

### My current solution:

```
parseTriplesD :: Parser Triples
parseTriplesD = parseTriples 
            >>= \rs -> return (Triples rs)
```

This function is pretty simple and correct. Takes the string and returns a object of the newtype Triples with the List of Triples created by parseTriples.

```
parseTriples :: Parser [Triple]
parseTriples = parseTriple 
            >>= \r -> ((string ";\n" >> parseTriples >>= \rs -> return (r:rs)) 
            P.<|>(return[r]))
```

This function needs some work. My idea is that I use another function which creates a Triple with tree Elements of the input string, ignores the /n and recursivly calls it self while adding the created triples to a return list. When this does not work because it can only create one Triple, it returns a list with the Triple. 
I somehow need to create the first Triple, and then use first element of this triple as the first element of the other ones.

**Question 1**
How do I create the first Triple and use the first Elements of the Triple for the other Triples?

```
parseTriple :: Parser Triple
parseTriple = P.many (letter<|>digit) >>= \a -> P.char ','
            >> P.many (letter<|>digit)>>= \b -> P.char ','
            >> P.many (letter<|>digit)>>= \c -> return ((a,b,c))
```

This function is pretty simple but I am not sure if its correct.
My idea is that it takes the first couple of characters of the string which are either a letter or a digit, up until the comma  "," , and saves these charcters in a.
It is repeated 3 times, and the creates and returns a Triple with the three elements.

**Question 2** 
How do I take only a few characters (which are either a letter or a digit EDIT: Or A SPACE Character) of the string up until the comma?
Is P.many (letter<|>digit) correct?

### What we are given:

**The Triples data structue:**

```
newtype Triples = Triples [Triple] deriving (Show,Eq)
type Triple = (String, String, String)
```

**Imports:**

```
import Test.HUnit (runTestTT,Test(TestLabel,TestList),(~?=))
import qualified Text.Parsec as P (char,runP,noneOf,many,(<|>),eof)
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String 
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Data.Maybe
```

**Test cases**

```
runParsec :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe a
runParsec parser input = case P.runP parser () "" input of
    Left  _ -> Nothing
    Right a -> Just a

-- | Tests the implementations of 'parseScore'.
main :: IO ()
main = do
    testresults <- runTestTT tests
    print testresults

-- | List of tests for 'parseScore'.
tests :: Test
tests = TestLabel "parseScoreTest" (TestList [
    runParsec parseTriplesD "0,1,2;\n2,3."   ~?= Just (Triples [("0","1","2"),("0","2","3")]),
    runParsec parseTriplesD "a,bcde ,23." ~?= Just (Triples [("a","bcde ","23")]),
    runParsec parseTriplesD "a,b,c;\n d,e;\n f,g;\n h,i." ~?= Just (Triples [("a","b","c"),("a","d","e"),("a","f","g"),("a","h","i")]),
    runParsec parseTriplesD "a,bcde23." ~?= Nothing,
    runParsec parseTriplesD "a,b,c;d,e;f,g;h,i." ~?= Nothing,
    runParsec parseTriplesD "a,b,c;\nd;\nf,g;\nh,i." ~?= Nothing
    ])
```

Comment: Your second test shows a space captured in the expected output on `"bcde "`. I thought you only wanted alphanumeric characters in the output. Is that a typo?

Comment: Ahh. Missed that one. We were not given direct task instructions, just the test cases. So I assumed that it was only alphanumeric character, but I totaly missed that space character. I am going to edit it in my Quesition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is:

1. Parse the first character
2. Parse a list of pairs
3. Add the first character to each of the pairs to create triples

Using `do` notation will make your code more readable.
You can use `alphaNum` as a shorthand for `letter <|> digit`.

```
parseTriplesD :: Parser Triples
parseTriplesD = Triples <$> parseTriples

parseTriples :: Parser [Triple]
parseTriples = do
    a <- parseString
    char ','
    pairs <- parsePair `sepBy1` string ";\n"
    char '.'
    eof
    return (map (\(b, c) -> (a, b, c)) pairs)

parsePair :: Parser (String, String)
parsePair = do
    first <- parseString
    char ','
    second <- parseString
    return (first, second)

parseString :: Parser String
parseString = many (char ' ') >> many (alphaNum <|> char ' ')
```

Comment: Great idea. didnt think of it. Could you explain pairs <- parsePair `sepBy1` (string ";\n" >> optional (char ' ')) a bit more? what does "sepBy 1 " and optional do?

Comment: Here's the documentation for [`sepBy1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:sepBy1) and [`optional`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:optional). `sepBy1` will parse a list of the first parameter separated by the second parameter. `optional` will try to parse something, but then ignores it if the match fails.